# Dynamically Apend data in html table from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table with following columns :

> no, name, oname, quantity

I have n number of records in the tables ,I want to fetch these records in an html table that dynamically increases'decreases its row length according to the number of rows in mysql database. I am trying following but its not working.can anyone help me out here

```
<?php
include './connection.php';

$query = "select * from orderdetails";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '<table border="1" style="width:600px" align=center >';
echo '<tr bgcolor="lavendar">';
echo '<td width="15%">Order No.</td>';
echo '<td>Name</td>';       
echo '<td>Order</td>';
echo '<td>Quantity</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' row['no'] '</td>';
   echo '<td>' row['name'] '</td>';
   echo '<td>' row['oname'] '</td>';
   echo '<td>' row['quantity'] '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are printing out your values, there are a few errors.

In this specific code block:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' row['no'] '</td>';
   echo '<td>' row['name'] '</td>';
   echo '<td>' row['oname'] '</td>';
   echo '<td>' row['quantity'] '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

First off all, you would want to **concatinate** your strings, PHP uses `.` for that.

For example, to concatinate "World!" to "Hello, ", to print out `Hello, World!`, you would use the following:

```
echo "Hello, " . "World!";
```

You are also missing a variable sign (**$**) in your code, when printing out the rows.

In your case, you're using `echo '<td>' row['no'] '</td>';`,
where it should have been **`echo '<td>' . $row['no'] . '</td>';`**

To clarify, your code should look like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['no'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['oname'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['quantity'] . '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Relevant PHP documentation:
[PHP String Concatination](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
[Echo documentation](https://www.php.net/echo)

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo-

```
row['no']
```

to

```
$row['no']
```

Similarly other variables too.